# replacing/hiding variables with a vector at compile time?

Tags: c++, templates, macros, metaprogramming

I've an evaluation function of a board game engine, that calculates a score using a set of variables in a way similar to this:

```
eval_params.h
const int bonusA=somevaluea;
const int bonusB=somevlaueb;
const MyEnumType bonusM[]={/*......*/};
```

and

```
eval.h
int eval(player p)
{
     int score=0;
     /*.....*/
     if(p.featureA) score+=bonusA;
     if(p.featureB) score+=bonusA;
     if(p.featureM) score+=bonusM[p.featureM.type];
     /*......*/
     return score;
}
```

and a tuner that needs to be able to modify the evaluation parameters and cal the eval function using the new values during tuning, unfortunately I can't just group the parameters by hand in a single array or vector for multiple reasons "one of which being readability, there are hundreds of them and they need to be separate when not being tuned",is it possible to somehow achieve that using macros, templates or any other language faculty (even if it is part of c++2y) without having to remove the original code?
for example something like

```
eval_params.h
int bonusA=somevaluea;
int bonusB=somevlaueb;
MyEnumType bonusM[]={/*......*/};
TUNE(bonusA,bonusB,MyEnumType);
```

would result in adding the RHSs to a global vector/s and convert the variable to references pointing to the data at such vector/s or anything similar ?

*the closest thing I found is this code from a chess engine called stockfish:
[tune.h](https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish/blob/tune/src/tune.h)
[ucioption](https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish/blob/tune/src/ucioption.cpp#L193) 
but I've no idea how it works.

Comment: How is the data organized when it's not being tuned? Is that flexible? Ultimately, because the data is in different places, there is no way to preserve your existing tuning function's interface without copying it all to a player struct before calling `eval`

Comment: @parktomatomi,most of the data that needs to be tuned is contained withing a single header file "eval_params.h" with a few variables declared within the evaluation function,I need a solution that dosn't modify the evaluation function itself.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. What I am asking is, where is the source of the values of `p.feature<X>`? For instance, are there a bunch of different structs with a `feature` member? Are the `feature` members in player each a pointer to an object?

Comment: @parktomatomi I don't think the source matters, but anyway it's just an example, in the actual code those features are complex properties of the game state that are calculated during evaluation, so I replaced them with a simplified statement in the example given.

Comment: Thanks for being patient with me @arthur. Is your entire game state in the `player` struct? Are there actions that modify only a part of the data?

Comment: @parktomatomi It's a board game similar to chess, in the actual code I don't have a player struct, instead I've a position class that holds the game data, the features can then be extracted from it, similar to how in chess you would check the position to see how many moves a piece has "mobility" and then reward a bonus based on the value of such feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use struct to pack multiple data variables in one like this

```
struct DataType {
  int bonusA=somevaluea;
  int bonusB=somevlaueb;
  MyEnumType bonusM[]={/*......*/};
};
```

then create variable from struct

```
DataType d;
```

Then pass it to functions by reference or pointer

```
doSomething(&d;
```